# How to fix this error in Python related to web.DataReader

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an error related to web.datareader. For some reason I can't figure out what is causing it. Any ideas?

```
!pip install mplfinance
!pip install seaborn
!pip install matplotlib

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

currency = "USD"
metric = "Close"

start = dt.datetime(2018,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

crypto = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'XRP', 'DASH', 'SC']
colnames = []

first = True

for ticker in crypto:
    data = web.DataReader(f"{ticker}-{currency}", "yahoo", start, end)
    if first:
        combined = data[[metric]].copy()
        colnames.append(ticker)
        combined.columns = colnames
        first = False
    else:
        combined = combined.join(data[metric])
        colnames.append(ticker)
        combined.columns = colnames

plt.yscale('log') # first show linear

for ticker in crypto:
    plt.plot(combined[ticker], label=ticker)

plt.legend(loc="upper right")

plt.show()

# # Correlation Heat Map

print(combined)

combined = combined.pct_change().corr(method='pearson')

sns.heatmap(combined, annot=True, cmap="coolwarm")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you not missing an import `import pandas_datareader.data as web` ? `web` seems to be undefined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two lines:

```
!pip install pandas-datareader
import pandas_datareader as web
```